# Vector pointing to vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, sfml

In my framework class I have this vector declared: `std::vector<sf::Drawable*> drawableStack;`

When the drawableStack is all filled up, I want to draw all the objects in a loop such as this:

```
void Framework::drawScreen()
{
    window->clear();

    std::vector<sf::Drawable*>::iterator itr;

    for(itr=drawableStack.begin(); itr!=drawableStack.end(); itr++)
    {
        window->draw(itr);
    }

    window->display();
}
```

window is declared in the header `sf::RenderWindow* window;` and the draw function is `sf::RenderWindow::draw(const sf::Drawable&)` and the error is `error: no matching function for call to 'sf::RenderWindow::draw(std::vector<sf::Drawable*>::iterator&'`. What do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the iterator. Change this line:

```
window->draw(itr);
```

to

```
window->draw(**itr);
```

You have to dereference it twice. Once to get from the iterator to the `sf::Drawable*` it points to, and a second time because the vector holds pointers and the function takes a reference as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why the solution works as well as what was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need to dereference both the iterator and the pointer:

```
window->draw(**itr);
```